# How can I make a link in HTML turn a color when hovering and remove the underline using CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a link in HTML turn a color when hovering and remove the underline using CSS?

Comment: @Strager: That was not a better edit.

Comment: @Rich B, ah, it seems you edited the post while I was editing it, thus my edit overwrote yours.  Sorry.

Comment: @strager: Not possible, as you were editing my revision, not the original post. But whatever.

Comment: @Rich B, I don't believe that was the case.  But whatever.  ;P

Comment: @Rich B, I clicked to edit based off revision 1.  Then, you clicked to edit, then posted your edit.  Then, I posted mine.  SO merged our edits, it seems; I did not have a chance to see yours (nor did I notice it).

Comment: @Diddytheboss: You definitely should not be rolling back to your revision.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to look at the [:hover pseudoselector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes), the [color property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#colors), and the [text-decoration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props) property.

```
a:hover { color: red; text-decoration: none; }
```

To assure your hyperlink is styled as you want (and does not conflict with other style rules), use [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules):

```
a:hover { color: red !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Comment: Also note that IE6 (possibly 7, not sure) ignores !important

Comment: using important is a bad move. you need to have propper specifity, nothing more

Answer (score 7):

Also in addition to stragers answer, make sure to declare the pseudo classes in the LoVe HAte way. You have to declare :link first, then :visited, then :hover and then :active. Otherwise some browsers may not apply the pseudo classes.

```
a:link{
 /*this only apllies to named anchors*/
}
a:visited{
 /*possible styles for visited links*/
}
a:hover{
 /*when mouse hovers over a-tag*/
 text-decoration:none;
 color:red;
}
a:active{
 /*possible styles on active (when a-tag is clicked)*/
}
```